# How to make images saved locally actually appear on my screen?

Tags: image, tkinter, label, python-imaging-library

Hello!
    i'm trying to have my  images appearing on a label by using this code

this is to save a random image from a particular URL

```
                def photo_1():
                    urls = "https://www.flickr.com/photos/flickr/galleries/72157644537473411/" # You may change this into other websites!
                    regex = '<img src="([^"]+)".*>'
                    pattern = re.compile(regex)
                    photofile=urllib.urlopen(urls)
                    raw_data=photofile.read()
                    download=re.findall(pattern,raw_data)
                    randomdownload=random.choice(download)
                    urllib.urlretrieve(randomdownload, "1.gif")
                    global done_button2
                    done_button2 = Button(photo_window, text = 'Click here to display your chosen image on the black screen!', width = 53, command = generate_1)
                    done_button2.grid(row = 5, sticky = N)
                    done_button.config(state='disabled')
```

and this is to have the saved image appearing on a label but apparently not working so well           ..

```
                def generate_1():
                    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("1.gif"))
                    image_area = Label(photo_window, image = img, width = 55, height = 5).grid(row=2)
                    global done_button3
                    done_button3 = Button(photo_window, text = 'Click here to save the second random image locally! ', width = 53, command = photo_2)
                    done_button3.grid(row = 6, sticky = N)
                    done_button2.config(state='disabled')
```

this was a part of my code and when i run this application i made,

the only thing i can see is a white rectangular shape and i would like it to be as big as a black label underneath (size of (55,5) )with the actual image appearing...

can anyone help me with this problem?
You might have thought that my English is not that great haha
but please have mercy!

Comment: This is covered in many places.  The problem is you open the image in a function.  See the box that starts with "Note" (it uses bitmapped but it is the same for all images) here http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/bitmapimage.htm